# How to find defined flash vars?

Tags: php, flash, actionscript-3

I am php developer, my html integrator has given me a swf file.

When integrated, I saw there are some parameters defined. I would like to edit them.
They are in an object tag like:

```
<object ...>
param name="flashvars" value="var1=val1&var2=val2..."
</object>
```

Where can I find thoses vars?

Thank you.

the integrator have moved away

Answer (score 7):

Pure AS3 project:

```
var flashvars : Object = LoaderInfo(this.root.loaderInfo).parameters;
```

Flex3 project:

```
var flashvars : Object = Application.application.parameters;
```

Flex4 project:

```
var flashvars : Object = FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.parameters
```

Now we can check them:

```
for (var key : String in flashvars)
    trace("var: " + key + ", value: " + flashvars[key]);
```